# contact form missing fields in email

Tags: php, html, forms

I am having a problem getting two variables to be sent from my contact form. 
when the form submits, I get all the fields except these which are empty
searchType: 
date. 
 I think I may have missed something but can not see what does anyone have any idea? I am also using javascript to create a cascading dropdown effect so that the dates are dependant on the course selected.

```
<label for="training">What kind of training?</label>
<select id="searchType" class="fixed-size-drop">
    <option value="sessions">Introduction to Marketing</option>
    <option value="files">Social Media Workshop</option>
    <option value="clients">Advanced Marketing Workshop</option>
    <option value="firstaid">First Aid Training</option>
</select>

<label for="date">Choose your Date:</label>
<select id="sessions" class="fixed-size-drop2">
    <option value="020914">2nd sept 2014</option>
    <option value="18_sept_14">18th sept 2014</option>
</select>

<select id="files" class="fixed-size-drop2">
    <option value="11_sept_14">11th sept 2014</option>
    <option value="18_sept_14">18th sept 2014</option>
</select>

<select id="clients" class="fixed-size-drop2">
    <option value="9_sept_14">9th sept 2014</option>
    <option value="25_sept_14">25th sept 2014</option>
</select>

<select id="firstaid" class="fixed-size-drop2">
    <option value="03_sept_14">3rd September 2014</option>
    <option value="16_sept_14">16th September 2014</option>
</select>
</div>

<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){

    // all your form processing code goes in here, including the mail() statement.
    $EmailFrom = "$name";
    $EmailTo = "email@email.co.uk";
    $Subject = "Online contact form";
    $name = trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'])); 
    $companyname = trim(stripslashes($_POST['companyname'])); 
    $position = trim(stripslashes($_POST['position'])); 
    $email = trim(stripslashes($_POST['email']));
    $phone = trim(stripslashes($_POST['phone']));
$searchType = trim(stripslashes($_POST['searchType']));
    $sessions = trim(stripslashes($_POST['sessions'])); 
    $newsletter = trim(stripslashes($_POST['newsletter'])); 

    // prepare email body text
    $Body = "";
    $Body .= "name: ";
    $Body .= $name;
    $Body .= "\n";
    $Body .= "companyname: ";
    $Body .= $companyname;
    $Body .= "\n";
    $Body .= "position: ";
    $Body .= $position;
    $Body .= "\n";
    $Body .= "email: ";
    $Body .= $email;
    $Body .= "\n";
    $Body .= "phone: ";
    $Body .= $phone;
    $Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "searchType: ";
    $Body .= $searchType;
    $Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "sessions: ";
    $Body .= $sessions;
    $Body .= "\n";
    $Body .= "newsletter: ";
    $Body .= $newsletter;
    $Body .= "\n";

    // send email 
    $success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: $EmailFrom");

    // redirect to success page 
    if ($success){
      print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=http://www.domain.co.uk/thankyou.html\">";
    }

    else{
      print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=http://www.domain.co.uk/error.html\">";
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the `name` attribute on your `select` elements.  This is the attribute which defines the name in the `$_POST` array.

e.g.

`<select id="sessions" class="fixed-size-drop2" name="sessions">`

Answer (score 1):

Your fields should have a name property for PHP to receives them Your select element is missing the name property:

```
<select id="searchType" class="fixed-size-drop">
```

should be

```
<select id="searchType" name="searchType" class="fixed-size-drop">
```